# How to write text file in PHP from a variable?

Tags: php, file

I have a piece of code that logs errors when it fails to commit to SQL server, it writes a "committed rolled back" then adds user ID

Here is a snippet of the code

```
 else {  
       $sqlsrv_rollback($conn); 
       $commiterror='Transaction rolled back $user_id}'; 
       $file = fopen("commiterror.txt", "w");
       echo fwrite($file, $commiterror); 
       fclose($file); 
     }
```

The code fails to work...

Comment: "the code fails to work" isn't helpful, what error message do you get? How does it error?

Comment: Why use'nt log class or log

Comment: $commiterror= is using single quotes, so the variable $user_id wont be inserted, try wrapping it in double quotes and remove the  bracket }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quotes of the message needs to modify so that `$user_id` will be treated as variable.

Use [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
else{  
   $sqlsrv_rollback($conn); 
   $commiterror = 'Transaction rolled back '.$user_id; //modify quotes 
   file_put_contents("commiterror.txt", $commiterror, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: @BrianKgCheruiyot glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember checking permission of the folder you want to write log. Make sure you have full rights to read edit update and delete.

Comment: I am now sortedd issue was different thing